# How to update a value after it is loaded inViewDidLoad in another file (Swift)?

Tags: swift

I have created all my views programatically and to the `UIView` I have created an extension. This extension is present in a different file called `App+Extensions.swift`

```
extension UIView { 
  func setupParentView() -> UIView {
    //...
  }
}
```

The `setupParentView()` gives me a view with my `navbar` and background colour. As the design is same everywhere I have used this function. This function is called everywhere in `viewDidLoad`. So, now in this function the navabar consists of `points` which need to updated every time the user has purchased/spent it.

So, now as this method is only called in `viewDidLoad` the function is not called again and the `point` value do not change in the navigation bar. So, how can I update the `point` value every time it is changed? I thought of using `Combine`, but this app will be available for `iOS 12` users as well, and I am not using RxSwift, so any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well ViewDidLoad won't get refreshed because your view is now in the stack hierarchy. Some override methods that do get called which have a relation to the view are viewWillAppear, viewDidDissapear, and viewDidAppear.

If your view is going back in forth and the point button needs to be updated everytime your view re-appears consider putting the "refresh" point number in one of the above methods.

Note if your sending info back and forth between two views its also best maybe implement a delegation pattern or an observer.

Answer (score 0):

Use notifications.

In other words, have `points` be a property of a global object that lives off in "data space" as a singleton. Now just use a property observer so that whenever anyone changes that object's `points` property, it emits a notification through the NotificationCenter.

That way, any view or view controller that needs to update whenever the `points` property changes just has to register for that notification when it comes into existence.

[Basically, this *is* the mechanism, or one of the mechanisms, that you would be replacing or even using directly if you were using Combine or RxSwift.]

Comment: Is there a part of what I said that you don't understand?

Comment: I haven't  used Notifications ever I little example will be helpful.

Comment: Okay, good answer! So, the docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter. Here's a little demo of using notification (post and observe): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch11p462notifications/bk1ch11p462notifications/ViewController.swift But it is _not_ an example of the complete architecture I described in my answer.

Comment: Here's a more realistic example. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/70e9543f1150bb0acc6276895bfbbf9d483fd2ad/bk2ch24p846backgroundDownload/ch37p1100backgroundDownload/AppDelegate.swift The app delegate does some downloading, and whenever it succeeds, it posts a notification. The view controller hears about this and picks up the new data (displaying the downloaded data as an image in the interface). That is very close to the sort of architecture you want to be using.

Comment: So, I tried your way and let's say I am in class A, it works. And now, if I go back `navigatioController.popViewController()` then, the previous class doesn't update the value? What can I do update it globally?

Comment: The previous class also has to register for this notification. _Everyone_ with an interest in this notification needs to have registered for it. That's the whole point. Notification is a broadcast mechanism, it talks to _everyone_ who has registered, simultaneously.

Comment: I've registered the previous class for this Notification and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I can't see your code. I answered the question in the terms you asked it. You may be making some mistake or wrong assumption, but how can I tell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215840/discussion-between-rob-and-matt).

Comment: Basically,you need a broadcast mechanism.The simplest way is to use NotificationCenter.but I suggest reactive framework is better choice such as Combine,RxSwift which give you more flexibility and clearer codes.

Comment: @matt This is my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382228/notification-centre-not-updating-values-in-different-classes-swift/62382902#62382902

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom view called NavBarView
2. This NavBarView has a property called `point`
3. `var point = 0 { didSet { updateView() } }`

You want to avoid singleton, single view object, so that not everything is coupled together.

You don't need RxSwift or notification to do this.